# how can I transport a suckerfish by automobile for 6 hours?

Tags: fish, travel

How can I transport my adult suckerfish, by automobile for 6 hours ?

Answer (score 4):

A 5 gallon bucket and a battery powered airstone is usually a good way to transport. The biggest concern is the fish running out of oxygen in a closed container and the larger the fish, the more quickly it will consume the oxygen in the water. The battery powered air pump will keep the water oxygenated. As long as the temperature doesn't drop too much, this method is typically easily good for a 6 hour trip. Longer trips you will need to worry about ammonia build up in the container, but for just 6 hours, there usually isn't a huge problem with ammonia.